# Showing the result of my controller on the page

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I would like to show the result from controller to view page in ajax codeigniter. This is my code I have used in my project. How to edit to show the result as table in the page. will you please help me to edit the code

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $(".submit_button").click(function() {
                var textcontent = $("#content").val();
                var dataString = 'content=' + textcontent;
                if (textcontent == '') {
                    alert("Enter some text..");
                    $("#content").focus();
                }
                else {
                    $("#flash").show();
                    $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<span class="load">Loading..</span>');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/Ajaxcontroller/getAttendence",
                        data: dataString,
                        cache: true,
                        success: function (html) {
                            $("#show").after(html);
                            document.getElementById('content').value = '';
                            $("#flash").hide();
                            $("#content").focus();
                        }  
                    });
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="main">
            <form method="post" name="form" action="">
                <textarea style="width:500px; font-size:14px; height:60px; font-weight:bold; resize:none;" name="content" id="content"></textarea><br />
                <input type="submit" value="Post" name="submit" class="submit_button"/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="space"></div>
        <div id="flash"></div>
        <div id="show"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

this is my controller

```
public function getAttendence()
{ 

if($this->input->post() && $this->input->is_ajax_request()){
  $credentials=array(

    'category' => $this->input->post('content'),

  );

        $this->load->model('Ajaxmodel');
        if($this->Ajaxmodel->selectAttendence($credentials)){
            $data['result']=$this->Ajaxmodel->selectAttendence($credentials);

        echo json_encode($data);
        }

    }   
  else{
  $this->load->view('Salarycontrol');
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$data['result'] = "here is your model";`

Then send it to view:

`$this->load->view('your_view_here', $data);`

Answer (score 0):

In controller you have to use "**echo**" statement to show HTML in our view page.

For example:

```
//Ajax example with my code

$('#suppliers').change(function()
 {
  var sup_id = $(this).val(); 
  if(sup_id != ''){
    $.ajax({
    url:BASE_URL+"orders/get_suppliers_details",
    type:'POST',
     data:{sup_id : sup_id},
     success:function(result)
     {
      if(result){
        $("#show").html(result);
      }else{
        echo "something went wrong.";
      }
     }  
    });   
  } 
}); 

public function get_suppliers_details(){

  $sup_id = $this->input->post('sup_id');    
  $sup_address = $this->orders_model->get_supplier_address_byId($sup_id);
  echo $sup_address[0]['address']."_".$sup_address[0]['supplier_type'];
  exit; 

}
```

this will displayed at " id show div"

another way:

```
public function get_suppliers_details()
{

  $sup_id = $this->input->post('sup_id');    
  $data['result'] = $this->orders_model->get_supplier_address_byId($sup_id);
  echo $this->load->view('orders/get_details.php',$data);

}

get_detail.php
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Address</td><td><?php echo $result['address']; ?></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

you can do what ever you want in get_details.php , It will displayed at "show div";

Sorry for my English.
Thank you.!

Comment: will u please check my controller@Bala chandar

Comment: Wait will check and let you know

Comment: i wants to show the result in the same view page@bala chandar

Comment: console your response. console.log(html.result), If you got index value, You have embed the html tags in javascript,  I would suggest you, 

$data['result'] = $this->model->function;
create a new file like ajax_view.php, then load that ajax_view.php like below.
"**echo $this->load->view('ajax_view', $data);**"  this ajax_view.php will display on the same page.

Comment: i have used like this in the view   :  <div id="show">
 <table>
 <tr>
  <?php foreach ($result as $value) {;?>
    <td><?php echo $value->id;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $value->category;?></td>
     <?php };?>
 </tr>
</table>...          getting error undefiend varriable result

Comment: i wants get the result in the same view @bala chandar

Answer (score 0):

I saw that your controller echoed a `json_decode`d php array:

echo json_encode($data);

So your output is a json string. So in your `success` you have to use that JSON string. Convert that JSON string to a JavaScript object.

```
success: function (html) {
     var res = JSON.parse(html);

     // now your result contains exactly the same things as the php array `$data` you decoded in the controller
}
```

Note that I’m assuming that `json_encode($data)` is the only thing being printed by the controller.
If something else is printed, `JSON.parse()` will give you error.

Comment: i am getting the result like this {"result":[{"id":"29","category":"sdm"}]} @nolmaginationguy

Comment: Yes, that will work. Now the var `res` in the code I wrote will have a member `result` which is the array you can get with `res["result"]` or `res.result`. See [JSON](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) for details.

Comment: will you please edit the code and send @nolmaginationGuy

Comment: I just showed you where you can start, I can’t code for you, since I don’t even know what’s the context. The line is where you handle the result of the controller

Comment: i have edited like this..  success: function(html){
  var result = JSON.parse(html);
$("#show").after(result); ... I am not getting the result.@nolmaginationguy

Comment: result is an object type. With a member named result which is an array of objects containing an id and a category, based on the first comment, create a string for a table row containing that data, and add it to the table using jQuery’s `append()`.

Comment: how to do that?